# supabase doesn't return error when a user tries to signup with an email that already exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I am using this code to create a user via signup

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({email, password,});
```

But i don't see any error When i console.log it like firebase which throws error codes and messages along with what went wrong. Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Acc. to [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup), it would return a fake user object or an error based on email, confirm options ...

Comment: The idea here is that you don't have to worry about Supabase not throwing errors. You can just treat it as a regular sign-up, and the user would go through the same flow. The user would receive a sign-in link, which would sign in the user upon clicking.